# "wieder jeden Tag"-meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is a sentence I've excerpted from one of the Goethe A1 Hören tasks. The transcript was unavailable and hence, the way I've comprehended it may be incorrect:

> Diese Woche haben wir in unserem Reisemagazin **wieder** jeden Tag um fünf und vierzig ein Gewinnspiel für Sie.

What does this "wieder" accomplish here exactly? It seems out of place to my unsophisticated mind.

Comment: (it probably said "um fünf **Uhr** vierzig")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adverb "wieder" is not related to "jeden Tag" but it simply means "again".

> Diese Woche haben wir [in unserem Reisemagazin] wieder [jeden Tag um 45] ein Gewinnspiel [für Sie].

This week we again have a sweepstake [for you] [in our travel magazine] [everyday at 45 (minutes)].

"wieder" could also be moved to other positions in the sentence. This might change the emphasis or what exactly the "wieder" refers to, e.g. this week again vs. every day again. Example:

> Diese Woche haben wir in unserem Reisemagazin jeden Tag um 45 wieder ein Gewinnspiel für Sie.

"um fünfundvierzig" might mean in the current/usual hour at 45 minutes. For example if the travel magazine is a daily radio broadcast from 9:00 to 10:00, this might mean that the sweepstake takes place at 9:45.

It could also be a a misheard "fünf Uhr vierzig" (5:40), but this time in the morning seems unlikely to me.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph: I guess OP just misheard "fünf **Uhr** vierzig".